# Exporting from several MXD files layers to images jpg using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, typeerror

I did a script where I want to export from several MXD's files the layers to images jpg. Each one MXD's file has 5 layers and I want to export each layer to images.

This my script:

```py
import arcpy, os
#Local variable
arcpy.env.workspace = ws = r'D:\Data\Mxd'
Output = r'D:\Result'

#List Mxd files
Mxd_list = arcpy.ListFiles ('*.mxd')
Mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(Mxd_list)
#Element in the layout map
titulo = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(Mxd_list,"TEXT_ELEMENT",'title')
fuente = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(Mxd_list,"TEXT_ELEMENT",'Source')

for mxd in Mxd_list:
    print mxd
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(Mxd_list, 'Pob*'):
        for elem in titulo:
            elem.text = lyr.name
            fuente.text = 'Source: Carencias CONEVAL, 2014'
            print lyr.name
            lyr.visible = True
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
            arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(Mxd, Salida+ "\\" + lyr.name + ".jpg")
            lyr.visible = False

del Mxd, Mxd_list
```

However, so far, my script doesn't work because I get the next error message and I don't understand what the mean. Someone can help me to figure out where is the problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 254, in run_nodebug
  File "<module1>", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 609, in __init__
    assert (os.path.isfile(mxd) or (mxd.lower() == "current")), gp.getIDMessage(89004, "Invalid MXD filename")
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\genericpath.py", line 37, in isfile
    st = os.stat(path)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Comment: That error looks like it comes from a longer script than the snippet that you present.  What error do you get when you run that precise snippet?  Where is the output of those print statements?

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about the focused Q&A format of this site which leads to [advice about writing code snippets](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers).

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is with this line:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = ws = r'D:\Data\Mxd'
```

This to my knowledge is not valid syntax?

It should be:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\Data\Mxd'
```

Also this line is incorrect:

```
Mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(Mxd_list)
```

Mxd_list is a LIST of MXD file names, to create a MapDocument object you pass a full path name which is a string but you are passing a LIST of file names which makes no sense. Suggest you read the [help file](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/mapdocument-class.htm) to understand the syntax of this Class constructor.

Comment: `arcpy.env.workspace = ws = r'D:\Data\Mxd'` should work I think - it is valid python syntax.  It will set both workspace and ws to the value.

Comment: :) I stand corrected! It's the VB in me that made me question it's syntax. I've left it in as I think it simplifies what the OP is trying to do which is set the environment setting workspace. Also they don't use the variable `ws` in rest of code.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing it that way, I've had trouble in the past when I tried it, but python allows it